# NestJS Authentication with Auth0 via `passport-jwt`

Tags: typescript, jwt, passport.js, auth0, nestjs

I'm trying to create a NestJS project that uses Auth0 for authentication, with the `passport-jwt` library (in conjunction with `@nestjs/passport`), though I am unable to get it to work. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I've read the docs over and over again but still can't find the problem.

### Code

#### /src/auth/jwt.strategy.ts

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { passportJwtSecret } from 'jwks-rsa';
import { xor } from 'lodash';
import { JwtPayload } from './interfaces/jwt-payload.interface';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
      }),

      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      audience: 'http://localhost:3000',
      issuer: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/`,
    });
  }

  validate(payload: JwtPayload) {
    if (
      xor(payload.scope.split(' '), ['openid', 'profile', 'email']).length > 0
    ) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(
        'JWT does not possess the requires scope (`openid profile email`).',
      );
    }
  }
}
```

#### /src/auth/interfaces/jwt-payload.interface

```
/* Doesn't do much, not really relevant */
import { JsonObject } from '../../common/interfaces/json-object.interface';

export interface JwtPayload extends JsonObject {
  /** Issuer (who created and signed this token) */
  iss?: string;
  /** Subject (whom the token refers to) */
  sub?: string;
  /** Audience (who or what the token is intended for) */
  aud?: string[];
  /** Issued at (seconds since Unix epoch) */
  iat?: number;
  /** Expiration time (seconds since Unix epoch) */
  exp?: number;
  /** Authorization party (the party to which this token was issued) */
  azp?: string;
  /** Token scope (what the token has access to) */
  scope?: string;
}
```

#### /src/auth/auth.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Module({
  imports: [PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' })],
  providers: [JwtStrategy],
  exports: [JwtStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

#### /src/app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';

@Module({
  imports: [AuthModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

#### /src/app.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }

  @Get('protected')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard())
  getProtected(): string {
    return 'This route is protected';
  }
}
```

A get request to `localhost:3000/protected` **WITH** a valid bearer token results in the error `{"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized"}`.

Full source can be found at https://github.com/jajaperson/nest-auth0

Thanks in advance;
James Jensen

Comment: Are you sure your `validate` function is getting called with the `payload`?

Comment: @ChauTran How would I go about doing that??? The documentation about this isn't really clear (or at least it isn't to me :) ).

Comment: well you put console.log in the validate method :)

Comment: I'll go do that, and get back to you :))

Comment: @ChauTran nope, it would appear not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All I had to do (once I stopped getting the `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE`) 
error, all I had to do was return `payload` if it was valid.

#### /src/auth/jwt.strategy.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
      }),

      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      audience: 'http://localhost:3000',
      issuer: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/`,
    });
  }

  validate(payload: JwtPayload): JwtPayload {
    if (
      xor(payload.scope.split(' '), ['openid', 'profile', 'email']).length > 0
    ) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(
        'JWT does not possess the requires scope (`openid profile email`).',
      );
    }
    return payload;
  }
}
```

Again, full (now functional) source code can be found at https://github.com/jajaperson/nestjs-auth0.