# In using JWKS with Auth0 what is the audience and issuer if I'm using localhost?

Tags: jwt, auth0, jwk

I've implemented JWT in my Node Koa app:

```
import Router from 'koa-router-middleware';
import { ApplicationState, ApplicationContext } from './types';
import configure from './configure';
import swagger from './swagger';
import healthcheck from './healthcheck';
import helloworld from './helloworld';
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
// import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'; << TODO
import * as koajwt from 'koa-jwt';

export default new Router<ApplicationState, ApplicationContext>()
  .use(configure)
  .use('/openapi.json', swagger)
  .use('/', helloworld)
  .use('/healthcheck', healthcheck)
  .use('/token', (ctx) => {
    const token = jwt.sign({ data: 'tokenData' }, 'secret');
    ctx.response.body = token;
  })
  // Secure routes
  .use(koajwt({ secret: 'secret' }))
  .use('/secure', helloworld)
  .middleware();
```

This works ^ and now I'm trying to get it working with Auth0 so I looked into JWKS and here's what I have:

```
import Router from 'koa-router-middleware';
import { ApplicationState, ApplicationContext } from './types';
import configure from './configure';
import swagger from './swagger';
import healthcheck from './healthcheck';
import helloworld from './helloworld';
// const jsonwebtoken = require('jsonwebtoken');
// import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'; << TODO
import * as jwt from 'koa-jwt';
const jwksRsa = require('jwks-rsa');

const jwksHost = 'omitted'
const audience = 'http://localhost:8080'
const issuer = '??'

export default new Router<ApplicationState, ApplicationContext>()
  .use(configure)
  .use('/openapi.json', swagger)
  .use('/', helloworld)
  .use('/healthcheck', healthcheck)
  .use(jwt({
    secret: jwksRsa.koaJwtSecret({
      cache: true,
      rateLimit: true,
      jwksRequestsPerMinute: 2,
      jwksUri: `${jwksHost}/.well-known/jwks.json`
    }),
    audience,
    issuer,
    algorithms: [ 'RS256' ]
  }))

  // Secure routes. Anything below this comment needs a jwt token
  .use('/secure', helloworld)
  .middleware();
```

First question: Can I do this from localhost or do I have to upload my code for it to work?

Second question: I am using the JWKS endpoint that Auth0 assigned to me when I created an account, am I right to assume that there's only one JWKS endpoint per account even if that account has multiple APIs? (on [this website](https://auth0.com/docs/jwks) it says that there's one per tenant which I assume means account but I want to confirm)

Third question: Aside from the audience and issuer, does this code look right or is it missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54544920/nestjs-authentication-with-auth0-via-passport-jwt)

Seems like it should be:

```
audience: 'http://localhost:3000', // With your port
issuer: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/` // Your Auth0 domain
```